# UIPrintInfo symbol not found error in iOS < 4.2

Tags: ios, iphone, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I want to run printer functionality in my iPhone app, which runs perfect in iOS 4.2 but when I'll try to run that app in iOS < 4.2, it gives me error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPrintInfo
```

What could be the cause and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, UIPrintInfo is only available in iOS 4.2 and higher.

What you need to do is check whether `UIPrintInfo` is available and if it is only then add the button that will allow the user to print:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo")) {
   // Add print button
}
```

Also weaklinkg the UIKit:
Go to your project and select the "Build Phases" tab, here you will find a list of the "link  Binary With libraries".
There should be required behind the UIKit.framework and changed it to optional.

Comment: Thanks for help but my application is going to be crash before t launches so where I should check this condition. Actually application may not get the framework before it launches, so where should I check it so It cannot be crashes..?

Comment: Try to weaklink the `UIKit` library.

Comment: Sorry but I can find anything from here can u plz expain it

Answer (score 1):

you can write this

> if (NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo")) {    // Add print button }

in your code as well as set one flag in your

> project settings -> build -> Other Linker Flags = -weak_framework and
>   UIKit.

Then you will not get any error at the time of compilation.
Plz take care that Other Linker Flags box should display first flag as -weak_framework and next is UIKit.

Hope this will help you.